# Reading geotiff as array gives Zero matrix or NoDataValue (-100000) in Gdal?

Tags: python, gdal

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np
red = gdal.Open("/home/ubuntu/Agriculture/data/sensefly/indices_sens_op/agri_sense_index_nir.tif")
red_array = red.ReadAsArray().astype(np.float32)
print (red_array)

out [[[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  ...
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  ...
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]]
```

the ortho is from Pix4d mapper and when called using numpy it gives only zero matrix or gives nodata value (-10000) in the matrix.

Comment: Your code is working when i try it on an orto of mine. Are you sure there is nothing wrong with your orto?

Comment: Are you sure your tiff is not actually all zeros?

Comment: thank you for reply. I am new to this field so How do I verify that tiff is not actually all zeros. I have QGIS, Arcgis software. Thanks

Comment: @ShanmugavelGowtham Pull it into QGIS then use the "Identify" tool to query different points.

Comment: band 1   value 37303   band 2 value 255. band 1 value keeps changing and band 2 values are 255 at all points. The

Comment: Can you upload your image to Google Drive or somewhere?

Comment: thank you and kindly find it using this link:    https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1EVmEbJ3VuVJNntR0W3pUCf_g6CUIDyWB?usp=sharing

Comment: I think so the corners of my ortho are black that takes no value.So when reading as numpy array it reads the corner data only. The center pixel values are mentioned as dot in array. I hope this could be correct.still looking for confirmation @Jon

Comment: I am in the field and can't download the large file. If you're using Spyder, you can look at the numpy array in the variable explorer to make sure that there are expected values in the array.  @ShanmugavelGowtham